# OrientDB does not show out relationships correctly when querying from vertex

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases, vertex

I am having a strange issue when querying Orientdb for a list of outgoing relationships from a node. Imagine that I have a node **#34:1** with 100 outgoing relationships of class **CONTACT_OF**. I can query OrientDB for this relationships using the vertex or using the edge just like this

**Using the vertex**

```
SELECT outE('CONTACT_OF') FROM #34:1
```

As a result OrientDB returns '[]'. This makes no sense at all, since the node has been connected with 100 contacts. I've tried with other kind of relationship and it works as expected, but for some reason that I don't understand it returns '[]' when querying for **CONTACT_OF**.

**Using the edge class**

```
SELECT FROM CONTACT_OF WHERE out=#34:1
```

As a result OrientDB returns the 100 records of contacts.

The question is why when executing

```
SELECT outE('CONTACT_OF') FROM #34:1
```

the result is an empty array?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I am using OrientDB community 2.1-rc3

Here is a sample of the anomaly in orientdb studio http://s8.postimg.org/5p1vxbk45/Captura.png

Comment: Still happening with rc5

Comment: Can you provide a sequence of inserts that show the problem?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the exact data, but I am using the java tinkerpop implementation with addVertex("class:PERSON") for vertices and addEdge("CONTACT_OF", ...) for every contact. In the first place I add every node of type PÊRSON and then y connect the #34:1 with a contact_of relationship

Comment: What does that image shows?
Is your database live? Or can you provide a copy of it?

Comment: It shows the result of SELECT FROM PERSON WHERE idUser="1379603866". I could provide a zipped copy of the database if it helps! ^^

Comment: Sure, some link to dropbox e.g.
Later today I'll look into it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. Here it is! https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8io0cmeo3yj6set/AABpAYVLl-TXM0Ox-GMD9njSa?dl=0

Comment: I had a similar issue yesterday. I fixed it by dropping and recreating the edge itself. I think that the cause of this is invalid data. Maybe an edge with old deleted vertices ?

Comment: I tried your theory and it works. If I delete the edge prior to inserting it again it works, but this is a very high performance app and I can't drop billions of relationships every time I have to insert them

Comment: BTW, even though I don't have concurrency enabled when inserting I'm getting this error very often -> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConcurrentModificationException: Cannot UPDATE the record #12:136 because the version is not the latest. Probably you are updating an old record or it has been modified by another user (db=v2464 your=v2463) [ONetworkProtocolBinary]